# How do I call in a method in a Form when a property of a class referenced in that form changes?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a form and i created a new class for it.but i cant call `Invalidate()` inside the class

My Code -

```
  public partial class CustomForm : Form
  {
      private bool showBorderLine;
      private Color borderLineColor;
      private int borderLineWidth;

    public CustomForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.DoubleBuffered = true;
        this.ResizeRedraw = true;
        this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw, true);
        this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;

        borderLineColor = Color.DodgerBlue;
        borderLineWidth = 1;
        showBorderLine = true;
    }

    [Category("Form Editor")]
    public bool ShowBorderLine
    {
        get { return showBorderLine; }
        set
        {
            showBorderLine = value; // Here I can able to call invalidate 
                                    // and it works perfectly
            this.Invalidate(true); 
        }
    }       

    private ResizeOptions resizeOptions = new ResizeOptions();

    [Category("Form Editor")]
    [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]
    public ResizeOptions ResizeOptions
    {
        get { return resizeOptions; }
        set
        {
            resizeOptions = value;
            this.Invalidate(true); // when I call invalidate here.it won't working. I hope I need to invalidate it in the Resize option Class for work perfectly
        }
    }
}

[TypeConverter(typeof(ExpandableObjectConverter))]
public class ResizeOptions // Inside this class i cant able to use invalidate method
{
    private bool resizeTop;
    private bool resizeBottom;
    // more fields

    public ResizeOptions()
    {
        resizeTop = true;
        resizeBottom = true;
        // more fields initialized
    }

    [Category("Form Editor")]
    public bool ResizeTop
    {
        get { return resizeTop; }
        set { resizeTop = value; } // I want to call invalidate method here
    }

    [Category("Form Editor")]
    public bool ResizeBottom
    {
        get { return resizeBottom; } 
        set { resizeBottom = value; } // I want to call invalidate method here
    }

    // more of the same
}
```

You can see the invalidate method is possible inside the Form Class but i cant able to use it in ResizeOptions Class

i call invalidate method for get design time support for properties.

if you want i can provide the full code

please help me.

Comment: You can't call it there because `ResizeOptions` has no knowledge of that method's existence. And why would/should it? Doing something like `resizeOptions.Invalidate()` doesn't make much sense. What would that even be invalidating? The options themselves? If you want a special `Invalidate` method there, you have to code it (or a way to call out to a specific control's `Invalidate`).

Comment: I want to call form invalidate method

Comment: I was being intentionally vague. Again, your `ResizeOptions` class has no knowledge of what a `Form` even is. Skim through that class and it should be more clear. If you **always** want `ResizeOptions` to be able to act on the behalf of a particular `Form`, you need to hold a reference to one.

Comment: Please just listen I just wanted to add the this.invalidate() method inside a class...leave it ResizeOption, it's just a sample class I wrote, so my problem is I want to invalidate some codes that written in an class...using this.Invalidate method

Comment: But you can't just do `this.Invalidate()`... `this` depends entirely on what class you're in. You might want to read over some OOP basics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ResizeOptions` is just a class that contains values. Even though you're using it in connection with a `Form`, it has no "awareness" that it is used within a form, and it shouldn't. It shouldn't need to know that when its values change, there is a form somewhere that should have its `Invalidate()` method called.

What's more, how can we even be sure there is a form to invalidate? We could do this:

```
var resizeOptions = new ResizeOptions();
```

Now there is no form at all. If we could somehow call `Invalidate()` from within this class, would would it invalidate?

What it can do is, when its values are changed, raise an event that says, "Hello, my values have changed!" and then other components, such as the form, can decide what they should do with that information.

To accomplish that you can create a delegate:

```
public delegate void ResizeOptionsChangedEventHandler(ResizeOptions sender);
```

Add an event in `ResizeOptions`:

```
public event ResizeOptionsChangedEventHandler ResizeOptionsChanged;
```

Raise it when you need to:

```
public bool ResizeTop
{
    get { return resizeTop; }
    set
    {
        resizeTop = value;
        ResizeOptionsChanged?.Invoke(this);
    }
}
```

Now `ResizeOptions` has done its part by letting anyone who cares know that it has changed. What, if anything, another class does with that information is up to that other class.

Now, in your form, you can subscribe to the event in the constructor:

```
public CustomForm()
{
    // other constructor stuff
    resizeOptions.ResizeOptionsChanged += ResizeOptions_ResizeOptionsChanged;
}
```

and in the property:

```
public ResizeOptions ResizeOptions
{
    get { return resizeOptions; }
    set
    {
        if (resizeOptions != null)
            resizeOptions.ResizeOptionsChanged -= ResizeOptions_ResizeOptionsChanged;
        resizeOptions = value;
        resizeOptions.ResizeOptionsChanged += ResizeOptions_ResizeOptionsChanged;
        this.Invalidate(true);
    }
}
```

using this event handler:

```
private void ResizeOptions_ResizeOptionsChanged(ResizeOptions sender)
{
    Invalidate(true);
}
```

Comment: Thanks You Very Much...Your Code Works Perfectly